# 2 PVC Pipes running from unit to basement

Tags: hvac

I have two 2" PVC pipes running from outside (AC unit) to the inside set up (furnace?). I need to cut these pipes and re run them since they are blocking the water heater which I need to take out. I wasnt sure what they did so didnt want to cut them yet. Is there water in them? Do I just turn off the unit first? When replacing do I use just regular PVC pipe and glue or is the some flex pipe solution? Any help would be great. I added some photos.[image: Blocking the water heater][image: Inside the unit][image: Outside]

Comment: @Ecnerwal sorry I am not sure the technical terms since I dont do HVAC. The pipes run from the outside unit (air conditioner) to the inside unit (furnace?).

Comment: which pipes are you referring to? I see condensate drain (white), heating loop, gas, ... and maybe direct-vent intake and exhaust. Plus water plumbing.

Comment: @keshlam the two 2" black pipes running down in front of the water heater then into the furnace

Comment: Not an expert, but pretty sure these are air intake and exhaust for the furnace, especially since they run outside.

Comment: Yea, I can't think of any reason for those in an AC unit--aside from a condensate drain, but that'd be a drain--not a pipe going up. I think Darth is correct that they are air intake/exhaust for a high-efficiency vented furnace. If the furnace is off, you should be able to cut those out.

Comment: The best way to figure this out, though, is to show us a photo of these pipes on the OUTSIDE of the house.

Comment: @DA01 I think that is correct. I added a photo of outside. If this is just exhaust can I use a flex type pipe?

Comment: Yes, direct vent intake/exhaust, judging by the connections shown in second photo. If so, one is exhaust fumes; you do(n't want that leaking and definitely don't want it open while furnace is running.

Comment: Yes, the outside makes it very clear. Make sure the furnace is off and cut them out as needed. I'd then replace with the same (looks like ABS). Reroute as needed.

Comment: That's not PVC, it's acrylonitrile butadiene styrene (ABS) pipe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. These  have nothing to do with and no connection to the AC compressor, which makes a lot more sense than the original question with no outside picture.

Flex pipe is probably not an option - if it IS an option it needs to be a type specifically approved by the furnace manufacturer.

While direct vent exhaust is relatively cool, so it can be run in plastic pipe, it is still quite deadly due to the carbon monoxide it contains, and you do not want to be casual about how it's handled, or you and your family won't wake up some day. It happens.

You might well plot out a different route for the pipes that is less inconvenient, but be sure it fits the manufacturer's requirements for the intake/vent system (or have it done, or checked, by your heating contractor.)

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why they blocked in the water heater, but I will just do hard lines again. To do this safley do I just turn off the AC and furnace before cutting them? Then just use the same PVC pipe and re glue them

Comment: @Packy Check the pipe carefully for printing- I think you'll find that DA01 is right and it's ABS, not PVC (different type of glue, and couplings) - actually, that can in fact be read in the first picture at full size.

Answer (score 0):

Those are acrylonitrile butadiene styrene (ABS) pipes, and can indeed be replaced and/or rerouted.

When assembling the plumbing, you'll want to use fittings and cements designed for use with ABS pipe. You'll also have to refer to the manufacturer's installation instructions for proper length and limitations on the number of bends.

For reference, the pipe that enters higher on the unit is the intake. It brings in air from outside, to be used for combustion.  The lower pipe is the exhaust, which carries harmful combustion byproducts outside.

While you complete the work, you'll want to insure the unit does not run. The best way to do this, is to turn it off at the breaker.